# Compute separate correlations, grouped by column value

Tags: python, pandas

Given 2 pandas dataframes,

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'one':['a','a','a','b','b','b'], 'two':[1,2,3,3,2,1]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'one':['a','a','a','b','b','b'], 'two':[4,3,2,2,3,4]})
```

A

```
  one   two
0   a   1
1   a   2
2   a   3
3   b   3
4   b   2
5   b   1
```

B

```
    one two
0   a   4
1   a   3
2   a   2
3   b   2
4   b   3
5   b   4
```

how can I compute the correlations `A[A['one']=='a']['two'].corr(B[B['one']['two'] =='a'])` and `A[A['one']=='b']['two'].corr(B[B['one']['two'] =='b'])` simultaneously? The end goal is to plot correlations as a function of the 'one' column values 'a' and 'b', i.e.

```
  corr
a  -1.0
b  -1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to iterate over the two groups would be:

```
x, y = A.groupby('one'), B.groupby('one')

res = {i[0]:i[1].two.corr(y.get_group(i[0]).two) for i in x}

pd.DataFrame(res.items())
#   0  1
#0  a -1
#1  b -1
```

Comment: This is true, I gave you a generic solution using groupby for this purpose!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

A = pd.DataFrame({'one':['a','a','a','b','b','b'], 'two':[1,2,3,3,2,1]})
B = pd.DataFrame({'one':['a','a','a','b','b','b'], 'two':[4,3,2,2,3,4]})

A = A.set_index('one').sort_index()
B = B.set_index('one').sort_index()
# as they must have the same number of obs on a or b in both dfs, do horizontal concat
df = pd.concat([A, B], keys=['A', 'B'], axis=1)

def cal_corr(group):
    return pd.Series({'corr': group.A.corrwith(group.B).values[0]})

df.groupby(level='one').apply(cal_corr)

Out[211]: 
     corr
one      
a      -1
b      -1
```

Comment: Up voted, but I accepted the other answer because it was more concise and didn't involve concatenation into a separate data frame. Thanks!